# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' (While installing TensorFlow)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, installation, windows-10

I am following this tutorial to install TensorFlow(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), but in the last command:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

I get this result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-02-16 12:56:50.178364: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

I have already installed `numpy` as you can see:

```
pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)
```

So why do I get this error message and how can I fix it on Windows 10?

Comment: just upgrade the numpy module using   pip install --upgrade numpy    it will fix your problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I upgraded `numpy` to `1.16.1` version and tried again the above command:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

and got this new result:

```
2019-02-16 13:12:40.611105: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
tf.Tensor(-1714.2305, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: It means you have successfully installed Tensorflow.

Comment: Upgrading `numpy` from `1.15.4` to `1.16.1` also fixed this for me.

Answer (score 15):

Upgrade the numpy to solve the error

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: This fixed it. Tensorflow 1.13 requires Numpy 1.16 and I had 1.14 instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was having numpy  `1.16.2` version but it was giving same error then i tried to install `1.16.1` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to force the upgrade numpy to the latest version.

```
pip install 'numpy==1.16' --force-reinstall
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `--upgrade` rather than a specific version might be better if you don't know what's latest

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you're using python 3.x by running it as

```py
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my numpy from 1.14.0 to 1.17.0 by the following command on Ubuntu 18.10.

> sudo python3.5 -m pip install numpy --upgrade

No import error then.

Answer (score 0):

there maybe multiple reasons for this error, thus, I would go through the solutions one by one; hopefully one of the steps will solve your problems:

1. Update your Numpy or reinstall it.
2. Check your interpreter directory (go to setting>project>python interpreter )and the Numpy package directory(in your terminal use this command pip show Numpy). These two directories should be similar, if they are not similar go to (setting>project>python interpreter>Add interpreter>show all> show interpreter path) and then add the package directory.
3. *If none of above solutions worked*, go to (setting>project>python interpreter>Add interpreter> add local interpreter) and change it from virtual environemnt to conda environemnt.