# GitHub Workflow CI Setup conda environment with mambaforge failing on windows: Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: numpy, github, conda, github-actions, workflow

I adapted the workflow for testing my own python package in ubuntu-latest and windows-latest with python 3.8 is below:

```
name: Test with Mamba in Linux & Windows

on:
  push:
   branches: [ continuous-integration ]
   tags:
     - "v*.*.*"
  pull_request:
   branches: [ continuous-integration ]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
   workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

build:

name: Python ${{ matrix.python-version }} ${{ matrix.os }}
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  fail-fast: false
  matrix:
    python-version: ['3.8']
    os: ["ubuntu-latest", "windows-latest"]
    include:
      - os: ubuntu-latest
        environment-file: etc/environment-dev.yml
        miniforge-variant: Mambaforge
        miniforge-version: 4.9.2-4
      - os: windows-latest
        environment-file: etc/environment-dev.yml
        miniforge-variant: Mambaforge
        miniforge-version: 4.9.2-4

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -l {0}

steps:

  - name: Checkout repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 2

  - name: Setup conda environment with mambaforge
    uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
    with:
      use-mamba: true
      activate-environment: ptac-dev
      python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      condarc-file: ${{ matrix.condarc-file }}
      environment-file: ${{ matrix.environment-file }}
      miniforge-variant: ${{ matrix.miniforge-variant }}
      miniforge-version: ${{ matrix.miniforge-version }}

  - name: Install PtAC (name of my own python package)
    run: |
      python setup.py install
      conda list
      conda info --all

  - name: Test code
    run: |
      coverage run --source ./ptac --module pytest --verbose
      coverage xml -i
      coverage report -m
  
  - name: Upload coverage report
    uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
```

using environment-dev.yml below:

```
  name: ptac-dev

  channels:
    - conda-forge
    - defaults

  dependencies:
    # required
    - python=3.8
    - osmnx==1.1.1
    - networkx>=2.5
    - numpy==1.20.3
    - Shapely==1.7.1
    - pyproj==3.1.0
    - geopandas==0.9.0
    - rasterio==1.2.4
    - pandas==1.2.4

    # linting/testing
    - pylint
    - coverage
    - flake8
    - isort
    - pydocstyle
    - pytest
    - sphinx
    - sphinx_rtd_theme
    - setuptools
```

The workflow runs through and passing all the tests in linux whereas it fails in windows with:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.13[pypy-7.3.9-final], pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: D:\a\PtAC\PtAC
collecting ... collected 0 items / 1 error
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_ptac.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\a\PtAC\PtAC\tests\test_ptac.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_ptac.py:6: in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py:126: in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py:112: in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_compat.py:7: in <module>
    import pandas as pd
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:17: in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
E   ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
E   numpy: 
E   
E   IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
E   
E   Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
E   many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
E   installed.
E   
E   We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
E   
E       https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
E   
E   Please note and check the following:
E   
E     * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\python.exe"
E     * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"
E   
E   and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
E   Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
E   
E   Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR tests/test_ptac.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================== 1 error in 1.73s ===============================
C:\Miniconda3\envs\ptac-dev\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:794: CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
  self._warn("No data was collected.", slug="no-data-collected")
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Any idea how I can fix the run on windows? I would be glad to have help on this issue. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Possibly check for differences in the two `conda list` outputs. Builds strings won’t matter, since it’s different platforms, but I’d want to see if different channels get used for some packages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`numpy/numpy` issue 15090](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15090) (more related to VSCode than GitHub Action docker container), check if `run: python -c "import numpy"`, just for testing, would work.

Check also if it does load/install other dependencies when you *remove* numpy from your `environment-dev.yml` (again, for testing, even if it leads to other errors)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! When I include `Run python -c "import numpy;print('numpy is imported.')`, it fails with the same error message:
`...
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Comment: @serra And [forcing numpy update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995002/6309) would not help? As described in "[`ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray Failed to Import`](https://www.pythonpool.com/solved-importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import/)", this is a version compatibility issue.

Comment: Thank you! @VonC I upgraded numpy >=1.22 in my environment.yml file, and the error message disapperaed. However, now I am facing with another one only on ubuntu with python 3.8 during test -it works with python 3.9 and 3.10: `import pyproj
/usr/share/miniconda3/envs/ptac-dev/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py:50: in <module>
    from pyproj import _datadir
E   ImportError: cannot import name '_datadir' from partially initialized module 'pyproj' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/share/miniconda3/envs/ptac-dev/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py)`

Comment: @serra Make sense, somehow. If it worked with python 3.9/3.10, is there any possibility to force those versions of Python during your GitHub Action execution?